# Finding Essential matrix (Matrix Multiplication Error)

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to do 3D reconstruction using opencv and I am pretty much following all the steps from the book :
OpenCV 2 Computer Vision Application Programming Cookbook by Robert Laganière.

My problem comes when trying to find the Essential Matrix. I do it this way :

```
  Mat fundemental= ransacTest(symMatches,keypoints1, keypoints2, outmatches);
 //ransacTest function by Computer Vision Application Programming Cookbook 

 cout<<endl<<fundemental<<endl;

 Mat  K=m_camera_data->get_K();
 //get_K() function defined previously 
 cout<<K<<endl;

 cout<<"K.T"<<K.t()<<endl;

 Mat_<double>  E = K.t() *fundemental* K; // Error
```

The functions ransacTest and get_K() have been defined previously and they seem to work fine. My fundamental matrix is the following

```
-7.65924601845777e-006   0.0052097327886         -0.179203748284864
-0.005202223611495075    -8.913278071309e-006    -0.5024237005766097
0.1843335279902164       0.4908219843516384       1
```

My K matrix is the following

```
 382.5   0    160

 0       0    120

 0       0     1
```

The transpose of K is done correctly.
The problem comes when I try to obtain the Essential matrix E. I get this error when running the program 
"OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (type == B<> && > in unknown function, file .. ....\src\opencv\modules\core\src\matmul.cpp, line 711"

I looked it up and I found a similar problem in this question [Opencv Matrix multiplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14795825/opencv-matrix-multiplication)
 but I tried to do what the answer said ( change the matrix  types) and I still got the same error.

I have also tried to use Gemm to  do matrix multiplication  but the same error appears.

I could really use some help!Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sounds like if the type of `K` is not double (CV_64F); probably it is float (CV_32F). Check that `K.type() == CV_64F`.

Comment: I just checked that and it is float!  thank you!  I just solved the problem. It was indeed a matrix type problem with my fundamental and my K . All i did now was declare fundamental as Mat_<float> every time and it seems to work!