# OpenCV matrix multiplication assertion fail inside class, but not outside

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix

Trying to avoid a C-style struct and making my first c++ class. An issue though...

Ok, so using OpenCv I define a minimal class to show the issue I'm having.
MatrixMathTest.cpp:

```
#include "MatrixMathTest.h"

MatrixMathTest::MatrixMathTest(){

    float temp_A[] = {1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0};
    Mat A = Mat(2,2, CV_32F , temp_A);
    float temp_x[] = {3.0, 2.0};
    Mat x = Mat(2,1, CV_32F , temp_x);
}

void MatrixMathTest::doSomeMatrixCalcs(){
    x = A * x;    //expecting matrix mults, not element wise mults
    A = A.inv();  //proper matrix inversion
}
```

Then MatrixMathTest.h:

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

class MatrixMathTest { 

public:                   
    MatrixMathTest();     
    void MatrixMathTest::doSomeMatrixCalcs(); 

private:
    Mat x;
    Mat A;
};
```

And then run this:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include "MatrixMathTest.h"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

void main(int argc, char** argv) {

    float temp_A[] = {1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0};
    Mat A = Mat(2,2, CV_32F , temp_A);
    A = A.inv();
    cout << A << endl;

    float temp_x[] = {3, 2};
    Mat x = Mat(2,1, CV_32F , temp_x);
    x = A * x;
    cout << x << endl;

    MatrixMathTest tester;
    tester.doSomeMatrixCalcs();
}
```

The same code in main will work as expected, but once it's in the class it fails:

[image: multError]

If I place the A.inv(); line first I get slightly different:

[image: inverse error]

There were no assertion failures when I ran the same code directly in main with CV_32F as the type. A search of that error message, [shows people solving it by changing the variable types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14795825/opencv-matrix-multiplication) but I have tried all the different number variable types the assertion(s) mention and more, it's simply left at CV_32F as this is the last I tried.

I figure it's something to do with being in the class ? ??

But what?   Or something else ?

Something (terribly basic?) I am yet to learn ?

... and if it is related to the type, how to reconcile wanting to eventually do both mults and inversions on the same matrices - do the different types in those assertions exclude that??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are masking the class variables `A` and `x` in `MatrixMathTest::MatrixMathTest()`.
Since you declare them as `Mat A = ...` then you are initializing these *temporary objects*, and not the *member objects* of your class.
That is, when you run the `doSomeMatrixCalcs()`, you are using the member objects `this.A` and `this.x`, but they were never initialized. Thus they contain bad data, and the operation fails.

Replace `Mat A = ...` with `A = ...` or `this.A = ...` and things should work better.

Comment: We must have been answering at the same time, so have a +1 from me :-)

Comment: Same comment as below (I saw that answer first) - but I see yours precludes it - thank you also very much... I had tried 'this->A' - but it didn't work which is obvious now ... also noted some discussion on SO that it wasn't the most highly regarded style anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

Your class constructor has hidden the member variables, try doing this instead:

```
MatrixMathTest::MatrixMathTest(){

    float temp_A[] = {1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0};
    A = Mat(2,2, CV_32F , temp_A);
    float temp_x[] = {3.0, 2.0};
    x = Mat(2,1, CV_32F , temp_x);
}
```

Note that I have removed the `Mat` from the `A` and `x` declarations. So previously you were creating local variables with the same names as your class member variables. Then when you came to call `doSomeMatrixCalcs`, the member variables it used were uninitialized, hence the assertions.

Comment: brilliant - thank you... Been a while since I tripped up on stuff like that! The separation between the .h file and the .cpp didn't help let alone the assertion red herrings. Well, I guess they made sense! Just not the direct sense that I needed.